# Android webview clipboard disappear

Tags: android, webview, copy, clipboard

**Application**

Currently I have a Android app with fragments (support library).
In a fragment there is a webview with a website in it.
The application need to run on Android 4 and higher.

**User needs**

The user needs to be able to copy text from the webview.

**Problem**

When the user do a long press the selection is made and direct after the selection is gone.

**What I tried **
Creating a activity with a webview solved the problem, but we can't use that in this app.

**Question**
Does someone have a clue where to find the source of this problem?
Somebody experience the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

The previous developer had disable the actionbar with this method in the MainActivity:

```
@Override
public ActionMode onWindowStartingActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
    return null;
}
```

When i removed it all problems are gone :)

Comment: this is 2 years ago and was private code for client, so sorry. Maybe you can post a question with the problem your having?